# Net Core - Getting "The default FirebaseApp already exists" even checking for null first

Tags: c#, firebase, .net-core

I am running firebase initialization as part of my notification topic class constructor, and I am running into the error "The default FirebaseApp already exists.". The issue is that I am already checking for null before the Create method is executed, and I am still getting the error.

Here is my relevant code:

```
 public TopicClient(string credsFile)
        {
            if (FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance == null)
            {
                FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
                {
                    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credsFile),
                });
            }
        }
```

What could be the problem? Is the issue that the create method is being invoked as part of the class constructor? Should this be part of the projects startup?
What other check can I run to prevent the execution of the Create method if there is already a default instance active?

Thank you for your time!